# Refresh GoogleMap on Android from the ListviewAdapter

Tags: android, google-maps, refresh, reload, listview-adapter

I am currently creating a google maps app and I am trying to get it to refresh after the user clicks on an item in a listview. However with the listviewadapter being in a different part of the code this is not going as planned. I've tried multiple ways including turning certain parts of the code to `static` however this only breaks the google maps code.

Here is the code from my main activity where the map is:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

GoogleMap googleMap;

// products JSONArray
JSONArray locations = null;

ListView townList;
ListViewAdapter townAdapter;
String[] townID;    
String[] townName;
ArrayList<TownSelector> arraylist = new ArrayList<TownSelector>();
public static String currentLocationID;

public String getLocationID()
{
    return this.currentLocationID;
}
public static String setLocationID(String l)
{
    return currentLocationID = l;
}

public static boolean refreshMap = false;

public boolean getRefreshMap()
{
    return this.refreshMap;
}
public static boolean setRefreshMap(Boolean m)
{
    return refreshMap = m;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //setContentView(R.layout.search);  

    // Locate the ListView in listview_main.xml
    townList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
}

private void setUpMap() {
    // enable MyLocation Layer of the Map
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // Get the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    // Get current Location
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    //set map type
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    // Get lattitude of the current location
    double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

    //get longitude of the current location
    double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

    //Create a LatLong object for the current location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);

    // show the current location in google map
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    // Zoom in the map
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13));
    //googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude)).title("Location").snippet("You're here"));
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllInfo extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Bars. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters            
        List<NameValuePair> paramsLocations = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL            
        JSONObject jsonLocations = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_locations, "GET", paramsLocations);

        //Get all Locations
        if(jsonLocations != null)
        {
            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Locations: ", jsonLocations.toString());
            try {

                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = jsonLocations.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Locations
                    locations = jsonLocations.getJSONArray(TAG_LOCATIONS);

                    // looping through All Offers
                    for (int i = 0; i < locations.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = locations.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_LID);
                        String locationName = c.getString(TAG_LNAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> locationsListMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        locationsListMap.put(TAG_LID, id);
                        locationsListMap.put(TAG_LNAME, locationName);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        locationList.add(locationsListMap);

                    }
                }                   
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;            
    } 

    }

}
```

}

Here is the code from the ListViewAdapter activity:

```
 view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {            

            MainActivity.setLocationID(locationlist.get(position).getID());
            MainActivity.setRefreshMap(true);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Any suggestions? I am tempted to add an update feature which will check for a static boolean to be turned from false to true when the user clicks a list item, however I believe there should be an easier way than this

EDIT:
I have added the `setOnItemClickListener`in the main activity and have entered a Log.d string just to see if it worked and I don't recieve any things after hitting any of the four Town names I have in the list

```
    townList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg) {
           Log.d("Hello","Why?");            
       } 
    });
```

Comment: You can check with boolean flag.

Comment: How do I do that? In the OnClick function in lisviewadapter?

Comment: Take one public static boolean variable in Map Activity and set its true when your map being refreshed. And when you click view in your lisviewadapter just check if it is true then refresh your map.

Comment: But how, I tried something like that before but when I try to refresh using `setUpMap();` and `new LoadAllInfo().execute();` it needs to be static for the listviewadapter code to read it but that breaks the google maps code

Comment: Why don't you use setOnItemClickListener for list view from MainActivity itself.

Comment: @Chitrang didn't think that was a possibility, I will give that a try

Comment: Yes, that should work for you. Let us know if it worked or stuck somewhere around.

Comment: @Chitrang I've added an update

Comment: Since I don't know what is in your adapter, try to remove focus from child view like buttons and other by having android:focusable="false". And then you should get click event on list view.

Comment: @Chitrang You're brilliant thank you What I hadn't done was remove the original `setOnClickListener` from the adapter view code. Once I did that it worked. Thank you. I'm going to add this as answer to the question to help people in the future. Unless you wish to as it was your suggestion

Comment: Glad that worked for you. And yes go ahead so that it will be helpful to others, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the fix thanks to Chitrang's comments above. First I added:

```
townList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg) {
       Log.d("Hello","Why?");            
   } 
});
```

And then when he mentioned I needed to remove some focus in the adapter I realized I hadn't deleted the previous `setOnClickListener` that I had left in the listviewadapter code.